# How can I send an Email with attachments using smartGwt 4.0?

Tags: java, smartgwt

I need to send an Email with selected attachments by user, 
I used `UploadItem` for the file selecting purpose.

Next thing is I not need to store the selected files, I just need to attach it to Email. 
Now I can send the Email with attachments but the thing is that attachment become as a `*.tmp` file format (if I select `*.txt` or `*.png` etc any of type).

I have attached my code part

> My DynamicForm()

```
private static DynamicForm ticketForm = new DynamicForm();
private static UploadItem uploadAttachment = new UploadItem("attachment");
private static TextItem name = new TextItem("senderName", "Name");
private static IButton submitButton = new IButton("Submit");
ticketForm.setEncoding(Encoding.MULTIPART);
ticketForm.setMethod(FormMethod.POST);
ticketForm.setDataSource(DS.getInstance());
ticketForm.setItems(name,uploadAttachment);
submitButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event){
               Explorer.getInstance().startAjaxOperation();
               ticketForm.setAction("submit.action"); //struts
               ticketForm.submitForm();
               Explorer.getInstance().finishAjaxOperation();
            }
        });
```

> My DS class

```
public class DS extends BaseDataSource {
    private static DS instance = null;

    public static DS getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DS();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public DS() {

        setRecordXPath("/");
        setDataFormat(DSDataFormat.JSON);

        setDataURL("submit.action");

        DataSourceTextField nameField = new DataSourceTextField("senderName", "senderName");
        DataSourceField attachmentField = new DataSourceField("attachment", FieldType.IMAGE, "attachment");

        setFields(nameField, attachmentField);
    }
}
```

from my support class i called following service

```
class Service(){
    sendEmail(model.getName,model.getAttachment){
        /*process*/
    }
}
```

> My Model class

```
class Model(){
    private String senderName;
    private File attachment;
    /* getter setters for this*/

}
```

> sent Email attachment like following image

[image]

[image]

I can't find any error.

I need to send any type of files `*.txt` or `*.png` etc but its correct format rather than `*.tmp` file

else if you provide me any code segment to create a selected file's `File` object in service layer also appreciated.

Comment: SmartGWT has nothing to do with send an email, so I would change the title of your question!

Comment: I think the `*.tmp` should be the file the user has loaded. Can you try to rename the `*.tmp` file to `*.txt` or `*.png`?

Comment: @miguialberto no user selecting a `.txt` but smartgwt converted it to `.tmp` file